# Bayes theorem usage for Ham/Spam detection

Tags: probability-theory, machine-learning, bayes-theorem, naive-bayes

I am trying to understand the probability calculations using Bayes theorem for a ham/spam classification problem (that uses Naive Bayes). I have a training set of ham and spam data with appropriate labels and assume that ham or spam can occur with the same probability.

So for a given text $(T)$ to classify as ham/spam I am using the following equation:

$P(Spam|T) = \frac{P(T|Spam)}{ P(T|Spam) + P(T|Ham)}$

I don't multiply the terms in the numerator with $P(Spam)$ or $P(Ham)$ since they are equal and would cancel out each other. Is this a correct model? The $P(T|Spam)$ just uses a naive multiplication of probabilities of individual words precalculated based on training data.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Anything specific you had in mind? This is just the use of Bayes' Theorem.